# GIven a container view, how to get child viewcontroller info

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers

I have a viewController added in containerView. If i know the containerView how can I get viewController which is added?

In my containerView, depending on scenario I'm loading viewController1 or viewController2. At some point, i need to extract the variable value from viewController

I'm trying to implement something like this

- viewController1 has variable -> dataOfVC1
- viewController2 has variable -> dataOfVC2

```
if let vc = "viewController in containerView is of type ViewController1" {
   let tempVar = vc.dataOfVC1
}
```

when i type containerView. -> all i can find something useful is subView..but how can i get viewController

how can i write my if condition?

Answer (score 0):

containerView use segue to present ViewController inside it, so u need to override prepare function

```
var currentVC: UIViewController?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "embedChildSegue1" {
      if let childVC = segue.destination as? ViewController1 {
        currentVC = childVC
      }
    }else if segue.identifier == "embedChildSegue2" {
      if let childVC = segue.destination as? ViewController2 {
        currentVC = childVC
      }
    }
}
```

and you can use if let again to check the current VC in other function

```
if let vc1 = currentVC as? ViewController1{
    let tempVar = vc1.dataOfVC1
}
```

Comment: thanks aiwiguna, but my question is different..if i know container view how can i get value of a variable in its viewcontroller

Comment: that how to get a variable from viewcontroller inside a containerview, the containerview will call a segue before viewdidload, so to get the viewcontroller inside containerview you need to override the prepare function, and you can get the instance of viewcontroller inside the container view

Comment: please check this https://github.com/aiwiguna/ExampleContainerView/tree/master/ExampleContainerView